# Can mesh analysis colours be applied to face material colour

Tags: python

The mesh analysis overhang tool gives me a coloured heatmap in edit mode. Is there any way to use these colours and apply them to the face material colours, so they are visible in object mode? perhaps using a python script.

I am using the 3d print toolbox at the moment to colour my faces, yet the mesh analysis tools gives a clearer indication.

Here is a comparison. 3d print toolbox coloured in object mode and mesh analysis in edit mode.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It has come to our attention that you rarely accept answers to your questions. This site works best if you [upvote helpful answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote), and if you feel it completely solved your problem please consider [marking it accpeted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 2):

It is currently not easy to get the data out of the mesh analysis tool via Python. The data is not available in Python. But there are possibilities.

**Solution: implement overhang in python**

Implement the mesh overhang functionality yourself. The C-code is located in `source/blender/blenkernel/intern#statvis_calc_overhang` and is quite easy to implement.

- Calculate the face normals.
- Determine angle between the face normal and the chosen axis (normalized dot product).
- Use a color ramp between the angle to get a nice coloring.

**Solution: change the API**

Ask the developers or patch blender yourself to change the API so that the data can be read. The data is currently stored in the `edit_bmesh` so it might become part of the bmesh api. Personally I would suggest a more cleaner approach outside `bmesh`

**Solution: Use as_pointer and interp the internal structures of Blender**

Use `as_pointer` to get a reference to the internal DNA structure of the mesh and use `ctypes` to read the data from the internal structures. But note that changes in ctypes might make your code invalid.

Comment: I am looking at this project again and it may be easier for me to select all the faces which are not selected by the mesh analysis. My python is not as advanced, please help?